# Refresh Combobox from SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm starting with C # and I meet some problems.

[image: Red= ADD TO DB AND REFRESH]

I would like to know how to refresh the data, when I save data in the second windows form (agregar_en_directorio)
and want to display the new data in the combo box of the first windows form (generar_tarjeta).

**The Conexion: conectaraBD.cs**

```
    public static SqlConnection ObtenerCOnexion()
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=myDatabase; User Id=user; Password=xxxx");
        Conn.Open();

        return Conn;
    }
```

**The Combo:**

```
    public void fillCombo()
    {
       string SQL = "select id_persona as identificador, clave_de_identificacion +' '+clave_de_la_dependencia +' '+grado_o_titulo+' '+nombre+' '+ ap+' '+ am DetallesCompletos from directorio";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection Conn2 = conectaraBD.ObtenerCOnexion())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, Conn2))
            {

                try
                {
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());                        
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al Cargar los Datos" + e.ToString(), "Error SQL",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        comboDe.DataSource = dt;
        comboDe.ValueMember = "identificador";
        comboDe.DisplayMember = "DetallesCompletos";
    }
```

Note: The used code for the combobox is the follow (used similars for the 3 combobox).

**And would help me your opinion of the GUI**

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

**i solved, but I had to change some things:**

```
    public static DataTable dataFortheCombos()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data source=SAMANIEGO-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=banco_de_datos; User Id=user; Password=xxx");/

        string query = "select id_person as identifier, identification_key +' '+dependence_key +' '+degree_or_title+' '+name+' '+ ap+' '+ am as completedetails from directory"; 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adap.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    public static AutoCompleteStringCollection autocompleteCombos()
    {
        DataTable dt = dataFortheCombos();

        AutoCompleteStringCollection coleccion = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();           
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            coleccion.Add(Convert.ToString(row["completedetails"]));
        }

        return coleccion;
    }

     public void fillCombos()
    {                                
        comboFrom.DataSource = dataFortheCombos();
        comboFrom.DisplayMember = "completedetails"; //This is the value shown on the combo for the user
        comboFrom.ValueMember = "identifier"; // The selectedc value insert as identifier (is a number)
        comboFrom.SelectedIndex = -1; //Clear the combo            

        //NOTE -> The others combos (urned over and sender) using the same data

    }
```

**The event --onfocus-- is used to call the refresh when the user is located in the combobox comboFrom**

```
     private void comboDe_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                comboFrom.DataSource = null //Clear the Combo Box
                 //NOTE -> The others combos (urned over and sender) using the same data
                fillCombos();                   
            }
```

Comment: FYI, your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataAdapter` all need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, take this into account, and I'm still improving the code. . .